# Unity InputSystem only registers right mouse button down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, game-development

I am using Unity's InputSystem and have two identical Actions ("Click" and "AltClick"). The Action Types are both Button.
My left mouse button input works fine. I get a call to my OnClick function for all three button stages (started, performed, and cancelled). The function OnAltClick only receives the started stage from right clicking.

Here is the code that receives InputValues from the PlayerInput Component

```
    public class InputManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public void OnMove(InputValue value) => GameEventsManager.Instance.InputEvents.Move(value);

        public void OnClick(InputValue value) => GameEventsManager.Instance.InputEvents.Click(value);

        public void OnAltClick(InputValue value) => GameEventsManager.Instance.InputEvents.AltClick(value);

        public void OnScroll(InputValue value) => GameEventsManager.Instance.InputEvents.Scroll(value);

        public void OnInteract(InputValue value) => GameEventsManager.Instance.InputEvents.Interact(value);

        public void OnToss(InputValue value) => GameEventsManager.Instance.InputEvents.Toss(value);
    }
```

A screenshot of my Input Actions window

[image: Input Actions window]

A screenshot of my Input Manager Object

[image: Input Manager Object]

Comment: Ive not seen it used that way before, but when used in the way Ive seen all the time I can confirm both left and right mouse buttons work as expected. eg, `controls.Newactionmap.Lmouse.performed += ctx => Debug.Log("Lmouse");` and a respective Rmouse which is a buttonaction with binding as is guessable.. works perfect

Comment: Yeah, I have breakpoints set up in my IDE on those lines and I see the breakpoint being hit three times for OnClick and once for OnAltClick